# Console no output when running a thread of Erlang in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, erlang, erlide

I'm a newbie of Erlang. The IDE worked well until I tied to create my first concurrent programme by using spawn method. 
If I type commend like "tut15:start()" to start a thread which should output a string, the console  will not show anything. 
I tried the module in CMD, it works. 
So I just wonder if it’s a bug or I should set my preferences at somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Handling output is tricky. The erlide console is using a remote shell and not all output goes to it (some may go to stdout directly, for example).

The console also has a lot of the problems.

Which one of the cases above applies to you is difficult to say without seeing the code, but my guess is that both apply.

The simplest workaround is to start an Erlang node manually (distributed) and connect to it by specifying the name in the launch configuration. This way you'll get the automatic reloading of changed code and the debugger. It's not pretty, but it works.

I will put the console at the top of the to-do list.